# Как управлять скоростью анимации в canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Коллеги, как думаете, как я могу под конец анимации плавно замедлять отрисовку круга? Опыт javascript = junior.

> **P.S. Обновил js , добавил функцию анимации, нашел здесь** http://kodhus.com/easings/ Понять бы как это юзать правильно

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('#cvs');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let levelOfKnowledge = document.querySelector('#percent');
let nameOfKnowledge = 'HTML'; //имя знания
let pi = Math.PI;
let coefficient = pi * 2 / 100;
let min = 0; //точка старта анимации
let maxPercent = 78; //процент знаний
let circleStyle = 50;

//функция которая вроде как должна помочь с плавностью анимации
// t: current time/currnet step
// b: starting position
// c: amount of change (end - start)
// d: total animation time/steps
function easeInOutQuart(t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
  return -c/2 * ((t-=2)*t*t*t - 2) + b;
}

let start = 0;
let frameRate = 60 / 1000;
let duration = 1000;
let currentStep = 0;
let newStep = 0;

let draw = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  currentStep++;
  newStep = easeInOutQuart(currentStep, start, start - maxPercent, frameRate * duration); //запишу в переменную что бы читалось лучше
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(190, 80%," + circleStyle + "%" + ")";
  ctx.lineWidth = "30";
  ctx.arc(150, 150, 100, 0, min / newStep, false); // использую здесь
  ctx.stroke();
  levelOfKnowledge.innerHTML = `${nameOfKnowledge}  ${Math.round(min)} %`;
  min++;
  circleStyle--;
  
  
  if (min <= maxPercent) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  } else {
    
    // alert(`Мой скилл ${nameOfKnowledge} равен ${maxPercent}% ✔`)
  }
  
};

draw();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#percent {
  color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.doghnuts {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="doghnuts">
  <canvas width="350" height="350" id="cvs"></canvas>
  <div id="percent"></div>
</div>
```

**Кому удобно на codepen: https://codepen.io/likeavenus/pen/XGdpzN**

***p.s. Нашёл такую функцию***, вроде как должна помочь, но пока не работает так как нужно. В описании сказано:

t: current time/currnet step

b: starting position

c: amount of change (end - start)

d: total animation time/steps

```
function easeInOutQuart(t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
  return -c/2 * ((t-=2)*t*t*t - 2) + b;
}
```

Comment: необходимо отталкиваться от времени, а не полагаться на асинхронные вызовы